# Elasticsearch suggest from multiple indices

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am working on `Elasticsearch`. I want to use `search suggestor` for multiple indices at a time. I have two indices, `tags` and `pool_tags` which has `name` field in each index. How to use suggestor on this two indices having a similarly named field `name`.

I tried naming the suggestor (`pool_tag_suggest` in `pool_tags`) differently and I tried. Here are the mappings

tags:

```
{
  "tags" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "name" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "suggest" : {
              "type" : "completion",
              "analyzer" : "simple",
              "preserve_separators" : true,
              "preserve_position_increments" : true,
              "max_input_length" : 50
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

pool_tags:

```
{
  "pool_tags" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "name" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "pool_tag_suggest" : {
              "type" : "completion",
              "analyzer" : "simple",
              "preserve_separators" : true,
              "preserve_position_increments" : true,
              "max_input_length" : 50
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

WHAT I TRIED

```
POST pool_tags,tags/_search
{
  "suggest": {
    "tags_suggestor": {
      "text": "ww",
      "term": {
        "field": "name.suggest"
      }
    },
    "pooltags_suggestor": {
      "text": "ww",
      "term": {
        "field": "name.pool_tag_suggest"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

ERROR

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "no mapping found for field [name.suggest]"
      },
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "no mapping found for field [name.pool_tag_suggest]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason" : "all shards failed",
    "phase" : "query",
    "grouped" : true,
    "failed_shards" : [
      {
        "shard" : 0,
        "index" : "pool_tags",
        "node" : "g2rCnS4PQMWyldWABVJawQ",
        "reason" : {
          "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
          "reason" : "no mapping found for field [name.suggest]"
        }
      },
      {
        "shard" : 0,
        "index" : "tags",
        "node" : "g2rCnS4PQMWyldWABVJawQ",
        "reason" : {
          "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
          "reason" : "no mapping found for field [name.pool_tag_suggest]"
        }
      }
    ],
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason" : "no mapping found for field [name.suggest]",
      "caused_by" : {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "no mapping found for field [name.suggest]"
      }
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem?

Comment: I used search as type field with same field name.